# Consolidate multiple rows of data into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data that needs to be consolidated:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| eventid    username   loginstart          loginend            data1 data2 data3 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1234       abc        2013-11-04 02:22:22  2013-11-04 02:32:22   2     4     0  |
| 1239       abc        2013-11-04 02:22:22  2013-11-04 02:32:22   1     0     0  |
| 1232       cdf        2013-11-04 02:22:22  2013-11-04 02:32:22   2     4     0  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

what i need is the output to look like the following:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| username   loginstart           loginend             data1 data2 data3 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| abc        2013-11-04 02:22:22  2013-11-04 02:32:22   3     4     0    |
| cdf        2013-11-04 02:22:22  2013-11-04 02:32:22   2     4     0    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Basically what the output has done is match the event that happend within the loginstart and loginend of that user and added the data up to give a single row.

Any tips would be welcome on achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an aggregate function `SUM()` and then `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT username, loginstart, loginend, SUM(data1) as TotData1, SUM(data2) as TotData2, SUM(data3) as TotData3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY username, loginstart, loginend
```

Example link [here](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Thanks..the obvious escaped me